How can I dynamically adjust a CSS grid layout for a memory game with a variable number of cards while maintaining responsive design?
I'm building a memory game and want to dynamically adjust the CSS grid layout to accommodate a variable number of cards. The challenge is to ensure that the card size remains consistent regardless of the number of cards, and that the layout remains responsive across different screen sizes. I'm unsure how to achieve this flexibility without breaking the design.
I tried using,
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(100px, 1fr));
to make the grid responsive and adjust the number of cards dynamically. I expected the cards to resize and maintain consistent spacing across different screen sizes. However, the cards are not resizing properly on smaller screens, and the layout breaks when the number of cards increases.

Post code as a [mcve] (hint: click the brackets button <>).  There are far too many factors as to why you cannot achieve your goal. First off there's a single line of CSS. We can't assume what the rest of your code is and going back and forth asking questions blindly is ridiculous.

I saw your query, and would like to suggest something:

Try using auto-fit instead of auto-fill.
Setup a max-width for the container to prevent it from stretching too far on larger screens.
Add a media query to provide responsiveness when changing to small screen.

I hope this helps.
